# How to use valid SSL certificate to make https connection using AFNetworking in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, https, afnetworking

I am trying to use Https in my ios app. I have the SSL certificates & the certificates are signed by CA and not self signed. The networking library I have been using is AFNetworking.How can I implement my SSL certificates.Can anyone help me with the steps to follow & the code required to implement the same.Below is the code of the method I have made for making the requests, in a subclass of AFHTTPRequestOperationManager:

```
func makeGetRequestToUrl (baseUrl : String , withParameters  params:    NSDictionary? , andCallback callback :ServiceResponse ){
       if !Utility.isNetworkAvailable() {
        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        Utility.showToastMessage("Please check your internet connection.", yOffset: Utility.alertOffset)
        return
    }
    self.responseSerializer = AFJSONResponseSerializer()
    self.GET(baseUrl, parameters: params, success: { (operation : AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject : AnyObject!) in
        if ((responseObject["status"] as? Int) ==   Utility.status.kFailure){
            if ((responseObject["json"] as! NSDictionary)["errorCode"] as! Int) == Utility.errorCodes.kSessionExpired{
                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                Utility.clearStoredUserDefaults()
                Utility.logout()
                Utility.showToastMessage("Session expired.Please sign in again.", yOffset: Utility.alertOffset)
            } else {
                callback(nil, responseObject);
            }
        } else {
            callback(nil, responseObject);
        }
    }) { (operation :AFHTTPRequestOperation! , error : NSError!) in
        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        Utility.showToastMessage("App is under maintainance.Please try after sometime.", yOffset: Utility.alertOffset)
    }
}
```

What change shall I do in this code to make the SSL working?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting this property in AFHTTPRequestOperationManager?

> AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = true

But still, this is not recommended for production state, followed by official AFNetworking github [page](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#security-policy).

Also, You can check if there any issues on the server side via [SSL Checker](https://www.sslshopper.com)